# weird redux-tool kit state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, redux-toolkit

I tried everything as per tutorial and connect my next.js 13 with the provider with `redux-toolkit` but I'm getting weird state not the state I defined.

[image: that's what I'm getting]

My code is exactly like the counter tutorial on react redux documentation.

I was expecting a state with a counter variable with a value of zero.

Comment: Is your app the "Free Gift Card Generator"? If not then it seems you are observing another React app's redux store. Select your app from the dropdown.

Comment: The @@INIT and RECORD_SYNC actions are special actions generated by the Redux store to indicate the initialization and synchronization of the state with the Redux devtools extension. These actions should not affect your application state, and they are mainly used by the devtools extension to keep track of the state changes in your application. If you are not seeing the state changes you made,

Comment: it is possible that the devtools extension is not correctly connected to your store or that the state changes are not properly dispatched through the store. You can try checking your store configuration and ensure that the devtools extension is correctly installed and enabled.

Comment: yes its confirmed bug in next js I have posted an issue they will fix it they hardcoded the router